# How to compare two tables and show only results not equal to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to do a sql query that would take two views and compare differences in data and display only the ones which is non zero. So far I have the below but it comes up with an error saying "subquery returned more than 1 value." Using SQL Server 2008

```
select * from stl_wk_vw where
ABS((select sum(missing+non_missing) as total from tdn_summary as b join stl_wk_vw as a on a.id = b.id group by b.id) 
-
(select sum(st_total) from stl_wk_vw as a join tdn_summary as b on a.id = b.id where   standard not like '%non' group by b.id)) > 0
```

Comment: How do you compare st1_wk_vw.* to sum(st_total)?  DOes st1_wk_vw have only one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    stl_wk_vw a
JOIN    tdn_summary b
ON      b.id = a.id
GROUP BY
        b.id
HAVING  ABS(SUM(missing + non_missing)) > SUM(CASE WHEN standard NOT LIKE '%non' THEN st_total END)
```